# Duplicate protocols in string, want just the domain

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to figure out a regex for something like this

`https://https://https://google.com` or `http://http://http://google.com`

I want to grab just `google.com`.

Here's what I've tried so far...

`https:\/\/(.*)|http:\/\/(.*)`

This works when the protocol shows up once, but more than that... kaboom.

Any help would be much appreciate, and if you have any, regex learning resources would also be nice.

Comment: Do you want to return a match if protocol parts are mixed? Say, `https://http://https://google.com`?

Comment: Didn't think of that, sure, why not!

Comment: I thought so, so the below solution will work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group to match 1 or more non whitespace characters,  and repeat the protocol 1+ times before:

```
(?:https?://)+(\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4aB81/1)

Comment: Great, an aside, where'd you learn that? I want to get better at regular expressions.

Comment: @teal'c Apart from SO, I think these are great websites http://www.rexegg.com/ and https://www.regular-expressions.info/